# How to wrap flexbox item to the next row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to build a website using CSS Flexbox.  I have a info bar at the top with and am trying to put a nav bar below it.  When I add the navbar, rather than wrapping to the next line, it is shown in the 3rd column of the infobar.  How can I (force?) get the navbar to begin on the next line?  I have defined a main container to display: flex, but do the direct children of the main container also need to be defined as 'flex' within the CSS? Most of my beginners code I have pasted here.  I appreciate any feedback and explanation on what I am doing wrong.  Thank you in advance.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-container {
  /*
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
*/
  color: #CD5B1C;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: "Cabin";
  font-size: 18px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f1f1f1, #f3f3f3);
}

.nav-container img {
  height: 35px;
}

.nav-container button {
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #262626, #000);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.nav-container button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-item {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  animation: ease-out;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/************************ INFOBAR START ************************/

.infobar {
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #CD5B1C;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Cabin";
  flex: 1 100%;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.infobar_email a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.infobar_phone {
  align-items: flex-end;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.infobar_email {
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}


/************************ INFOBAR END ************************/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="infobar infobar_phone">+1 (111) 111-1111</div>
    <div class="infobar infobar_email">
      <ahref="mailto:info@domain.com?subject=info">info@domain.com</a>
    </div>

    <nav class="nav-container">
      <div class="navlogo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo1.png" alt="Logo1">
          <img src="./assets/logo2.png" alt="Logo2">
        </a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-item">nav-item-1</li>
        <li class="nav-item">nav-item-2</li>
        <li class="nav-item">nav-item-3</li>
        <li class="nav-item">nav-item-4</li>
        <li class="nav-item">nav-item-5</li>
      </ul>

      <div class="requesthelp">
        <button type="button">Request Help</button>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for this you want to tell your flex container to allow wrapping by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` and then you want to tell your nav component to be full width by adding `width: 100%` to it.

You will also want to change the flex-basis on the other elements to 50% will make them share the top row.

```css
* {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      color: #fff;
      flex-wrap: wrap; /* ADD THIS --------------- */
    }

    .nav-container {
      /*
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    */
      color: #CD5B1C;
      padding-top: 1em;
      padding-bottom: 1em;
      font-family: "Cabin";
      font-size: 18px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f1f1f1, #f3f3f3);
      width: 100%; /* ADD THIS ------------------ */
    }

    .nav-container img {
      height: 35px;
    }

    .nav-container button {
      width: 175px;
      height: 50px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #262626, #000);
      color: #fff;
      border: 0;
      border-radius: 1em;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 1em;
    }

    .nav-container button:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    .nav-links {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      list-style-type: none;
      align-items: center;
      width: 35%;
      margin-left: 30%;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nav-item {
      margin: 0.3rem;
      transition-duration: 0.3s;
      animation: ease-out;
    }

    .nav-item:hover {
      transform: scale(1.1);
    }


    /************************ INFOBAR START ************************/

    .infobar {
      height: 2em;
      background-color: #CD5B1C;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: "Cabin";
      flex: 1 50%; /* ADD THIS ----------------- */
      color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
    }

    .infobar_email a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: normal;
    }

    .infobar_phone {
      align-items: flex-end;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: pink;
    }

    .infobar_email {
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding-left: 10px;
      background-color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="container">

        <div class="infobar infobar_phone">+1 (111) 111-1111</div>
        <div class="infobar infobar_email">
          <ahref="mailto:info@domain.com?subject=info">info@domain.com</a>
        </div>

        <nav class="nav-container">
          <div class="navlogo">
            <a href="index.html">
              <img src="./assets/logo1.png" alt="Logo1">
              <img src="./assets/logo2.png" alt="Logo2">
            </a>
          </div>

          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li class="nav-item">nav-item-1</li>
            <li class="nav-item">nav-item-2</li>
            <li class="nav-item">nav-item-3</li>
            <li class="nav-item">nav-item-4</li>
            <li class="nav-item">nav-item-5</li>
          </ul>

          <div class="requesthelp">
            <button type="button">Request Help</button>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked.  I guess I need to go back and look at how flex basis works as that seems to be the main issue I was encountering.  Thanks again Brett.